# Jquery ajax disable encoding of urls

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to use jQuery to make requests to a REST API (wordpress).
Due to encoding this

`http://localhost:8040/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&filter[meta_key]=holiday_type&filter[meta_value]=villa&per_page=2`

becomes this

`http://localhost:8040/?rest_route=%2Fwp%2Fv2%2Fposts&filter%5Bmeta_key%5D=holiday_type&filter%5Bmeta_value
%5D=hotel&`

Causing the expected result to be completely different. Is there any way to disable encoding??

Comment: browser by default encodes this, you can decode in API controller

Comment: So I'd have to modify the default functionality of the class responsible for receiving urls?